# How to setup a java project with default, compile and test configurations using Ivy?

Tags: java, eclipse, ivy, ibm-rad

I am working on IBM RAD 8.5 and trying to configure Apache Ivy framework for my java project. As I am about to add Ivy managed library I do not see the compile and test configurations being listed. Is there a way I can add these configurations now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurations are listed in your ivy file.

### How to use ivy configurations

Ivy configurations can be used to emulate Maven scopes, but in fact an ivy configuration can represent any logical grouping of dependencies.

Here are the 3 standard classpaths required in any Java build:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
</configurations>
```

Note the "extends" syntax that enables you to create larger sets. For example, the **runtime** set of jars also includes anything needed to **compile** the code your code.

Ivy configurations are difficult to understand until you realise that they can be used to selectively populate an ANT path:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>

<javac ..... classpathref="compile.path"/>
```

Or used to selectively populate a directory

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="build/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact].[ext]" conf="runtime"/>
```

### Configuration mappings

Mappings are used to decide how groups of jars in your project relate to groups of jars in other projects.

This normally happens as follows:

```
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.4" conf="compile->default"/>
```

Here our **compile** configuration is populate by the remote **default** configuration (normally the other modules compile dependencies)

Comment: Thanks! It showed up the compile and test configurations after I added those configurations to ivy.xml.